# Error. .commit() in Fragments in onCreate method

Tags: android, android-fragments, commit

So, here's myActivity.java

Basically, I'm getting an error in onCreate method when I'm trying to use .commit()
So, just unsure of why is that. Could use some guidance. Thanks!

Also, a beginner with Fragments so, gets me a little puzzled from time to time.

It shows me that it "Cannot resolve method commit()".

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()
                            .commit();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A Forecast fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

        public ForecastFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

            String[] forecastArray={
                    "Right Now - Hot. Grab a Lemonade!",
                    "Today -  Boiling! Feels more like a Heat Furnace!",
                    "Tomorrow - Rains! Carry an Umbrella!",
                    "Tuesday - Hailstones!",
                    "Wednesday - Stormy",
                    "Thursday - Snowfall!",
                    "Friday - Rebecca Black",
                    "Saturday - Thunder!",
                    "Sunday - Just right." };

            List<String>weekForecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

             mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    weekForecast);

            ListView listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


            return rootView;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace of your error/exception

Comment: You are still missing the bracket specified by @tolgap in your question. And no one knows what the new error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment().
                        commit()); //<-----

    }
```

`commit()` is a method on the `FragmentTransaction`, not on the `Fragment`. So change your code to this:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();

    }
```

Comment: Did that. That was a mistake. It still shows me an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting confused with fragments confused you shouldn't be concatenating all these things, do em in seperate lines until you're fully comfortable:

```
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()
                        .commit();
```

becomes

```
ForecastFragment newFragment = new ForecastFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment );
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```